# Button move to navbar when windows scroll

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have 4 buttons. Button 1, button 2, button 3 and button 4.

[image]

when I want to scroll down my windows, the buttons should be automatically go to navbar

[image]

I do that now but unfortunely when Browser to zoom in, the buttons will disorganized

[image]

My Code.

```
<div class="row scr_bot">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="draft()"><i class="fas fa-save"> </i> Button 1</button>

                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="save()"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Button 2</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="cancel()"><i class="fas fa-times"> </i> Button 3</button>

                                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btnAdd" type="button"><i class="fas fa-table"> </i> Button 4</button>
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var aTop = 230;
        if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
            // console.log('header just passed.');
            $('.scr_bot').css('position','fixed');
            $('.scr_bot').css('z-index','199');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','-590px');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-left','0px');
            // instead of alert you can use to show your ad
            // $('.scr_bot').fadeIn(10000);
        }else{
            $('.scr_bot').css('position','relative');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','0px');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-left','-20px');
            // $('.scr_bot').css('z-index','9999');
            // $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','100px');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: input code in my thread done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript.

```
    $(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var aTop = 230;
        if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
            // console.log('header just passed.');
            $('.scr_bot').css('position','fixed');
            $('.scr_bot').css('z-index','99');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','-590px');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-left','20px');
            // instead of alert you can use to show your ad
            // $('.scr_bot').fadeIn(10000);
        }else{
            $('.scr_bot').css('position','relative');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','0px');
            $('.scr_bot').css('margin-left','-20px');
            // $('.scr_bot').css('z-index','9999');
            // $('.scr_bot').css('margin-top','100px');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the buttons, why dont make 2 dedicated button groups? 1 in your menu bar and 1 in your page footer

If you then use the .scrollTop to hide 1 and display the other.

So you can style both the button groups way easier

Comment: can you give me example ?

Comment: my button are not go to navbar

Comment: My code was only a concept of what you could do, make 2 different group of buttons that you place in your footer, and 1 in your menu. Then make a Js script that makes one visible on your scroll position while hiding the other